# Creating a Context Provider w/ Lifecycle Methods & Best Possible Way

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to create a context provider within a react application that can utilize the lifecycle methods for data retrieval before it actually renders the first time. I am also looking to make the structure of the component better. Does anyone have any recommendations?

```
import React from 'react'

let defaultValue = {
    state: {
        accountID: 4885,

    },
}

export const Data = React.createContext(defaultValue)

interface State {
    getFeatureData: any
}

// Provider Component
export default class DataProvider extends React.Component<null, State> {
    state = defaultValue.state

    componentDidMount() {
        // something here?

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Data.Provider
                    value={{
                        state: this.state
                    }}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </Data.Provider>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to maintain a loading state and render the Provider once the data is available

```js
import React from 'react'

let defaultValue = {
    state: {
        accountID: 4885,
        loading: true

    },
}

export const Data = React.createContext(defaultValue)

interface State {
    getFeatureData: any,
    loading: boolean
}

// Provider Component
export default class DataProvider extends React.Component<null, State> {
    state = defaultValue.state

    componentDidMount() {
        // something here?
        APICall().then(() => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
        })

    }

    render() {
        const { loading, ...rest} = this.state;
        if (this.state.loading) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>; // or you can return an interactive loader here
        }
        return (
            <>
                <Data.Provider
                    value={{
                        state: rest
                    }}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </Data.Provider>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/342wv6ronp)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I can't even get console logs working from the componentDidMount statement. The debugger isn't even working.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also APICall in above method is just an example. you may have axios or fetch or whatever async thing you want to do there

Comment: I am running a fetch request and I am not getting any errors

Comment: okay, please check that you are setting the correct default state,  second check that your state is set to false correctly. Also type the state correctly in interface